# Why are ECG channels labelled as an EEG channel?

Tags: mne-python

[image: Raw data clearly contains an ECG channel]

[image: Yet raw.info shows EEG channels as 'Not available']

Raw data clearly contains an ECG channel. Yet raw.info shows ECG channels as 'Not available'.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw.set_channel_types

Eg.) raw.set_channel_types({'ECG1-ECG2':'ecg'})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).